# About odd functions and improper integrals e.g. $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\sin x \; dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, definition

> Does $\displaystyle \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\sin x \; dx$ converge?

Since $\sin x$ is an odd function, and we know that in definite integrals $\displaystyle \int^{a}_{-a}\sin x \; dx=0$ then does that simply implies to improper integrals as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in order for an integral to converge both $\int_0^{\infty} f(x) dx$ and $\int_{-\infty}^{0} f(x) dx$ must converge. $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sin(x)dx$ converges in principal value however.

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sin(x)dx$ is DEFINED as the sum $\int_{-\infty}^{0} f(x) dx+\int_0^{\infty} f(x) dx$ where both converge, so no $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sin(x) dx$ does NOT exist. However the way you are talking about is called the "Cauchy principal value" which means $\lim_{a\to\infty} \int_{-a}^{a} \sin(x) dx$ which DOES exist.

Comment: What is principal value?

Comment: I think so, so we can use that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sin(x) dx=\lim_{a\to\infty} \int_{-a}^{a} \sin(x) dx =0$ without decomposing it to $-\infty,0$ and $0,\infty$?

Comment: @kuhaku They're two completely different things. What you're talking about is principal value, which is NOT how the integral is defined. You're talking about the Cauchy principal value, which is NOT how an integral is defined.

Comment: But aren't improper integrals solved like this: $\int^{\infty}_a f(x) dx = \lim_{b\to\infty} \int ^b_a f(x)dx$?

Comment: They aren't "solved" like that, they are *defined* like that. And $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx$ is *defined* as $\lim_{a\to -\infty} \lim_{b\to\infty} \int_a^b f(x) dx$. How you take this limit shouldn't matter. If one limit doesn't exist, the overall improper integral doesn't exist. @kuhaku

Comment: @kuhaku For example if $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{0}f(x)dx=-\infty$ and $\int\limits_0^{+\infty}f(x)dx=+\infty$ then you'll get an indeterminate form adding them.

Comment: @metacompactness and this is the case with $sinx$. How can we show that those two does not converge but the expression in my question does? It's kind of confusing to be honest.

Comment: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sin(x)dx$ is indeterminate. Hower the Cauchy principal value of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sin(x)dx$ is 0 that doesn't mean that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sin(x)dx=0$.